# Prototyping Web App Framework

Tags: web-applications, frameworks, centos

I've been searching SO for ideas and suggestions on what best to use for prototyping a web app (see related question section).

I have 3 weeks to created a prototype to demo. All functionality is specified. The UI is not but this is not required for the demo.

In the past I have built highly bespoke solution in Perl and/or PHP, using JavaScript (JQuery et al. for UI).

This time my team will be significantly larger so an "off the shelf" framework would be preferable. It will also need to run on Cent OS 5.

I want something that handles:

- Registration
- Login / out
- Navigation
- DB access

But with enough flexibility so I won't have to hack it too much. In addition the learning curve needs to be as shallow as possible, I can only devote 1 week at most learning the basics.

*I will consider all ideas and suggestions and document the process here.*

#### Related Questions

1. [Choosing a simple web application framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448909/choosing-a-simple-web-application-framework)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490210/python-web-framework-not-app-framework-or-cms-framework

Comment: I'm sitting with the same problem, except I don't have the luxury of prototyping - it will have to be evolutionary development. Please post what your solution/findings are.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a LAMP stack, [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org) is a pretty good framework to go with.

It's very much rails-like and it pretty much has all the features you would expect of a framework such as [ZF](http://framework.zend.com), [CI](http://codeigniter.com) and [Kohana](http://kohanaphp.com). I'm sold on its `bake` code generator that makes doing CRUD functionality - perfect for rapidly prototyping semi-functional UI stuff.